# Improving maze search

Tags: java, recursion, backtracking, maze

I made a simple maze search algorithm that blindly runs into every direction of a cell
to check if the goal has been found. It can find the goal, but the solution is still bad, because it doesn't terminate the other recursive calls when the goal has been found
and it draws all the paths it has gone and not only one possible path to the goal. How could I improve that?

The basic algorithm in pseudocode is like that:

```
function searchMaze(start_point, end_point, maze) {

 // If current point is goal I would like to abort other recursive calls
 if(start_point.equals(end_point)) {
   pathFound = true;
   drawPathInArray(); 
    return;
  }
 else {
    // if current point is not inside the array
   if(start_point_not_within_array)
   return
   else {
     // if current point is a wall or a cell that has already been visited
     if(cell_is_wall || cell_is_visited)
       return;
      else {
           // mark cell as possible path
           markCellInPathArray("#");
           setCellVisited();
           searchMaze(left_from_start_point, end_point, maze);
           searchMaze(right_from_start_point, end_point, maze);
           searchMaze(above_start_point, end_point, maze);
           searchMaze(below_start_point, end_point, maze); 
      }
   }
  }
}
```

Comment: You are providing us not enough constraints on your algorithm. Please edit by adding:
1) How do you want to recur
2) Terminate condition

Comment: Try using the BFS - breadth-first search. It can be implemented without using recursion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have the function return a boolean. Whenever you've found a path to the goal, return true, otherwise, return false. Return once you get a return value of true from one of the recursive calls.

The changes involved would be appropriate return statements and changing your 4 recursive calls to something like:

```
if (searchMaze(left_from_start_point, end_point, maze))
  return true;
if (searchMaze(right_from_start_point, end_point, maze))
  return true;
if (searchMaze(above_start_point, end_point, maze))
  return true;
if (searchMaze(below_start_point, end_point, maze))
  return true;
```

Also, shouldn't you have a `setCellNotVisited()` at the end there?

**Note:** I see you already have a `pathFound` variable (presumably a class variable). In this case Marco's solution is probably preferred, but it could be better to change it to a return value instead.

Comment: Thanks, that was that I have forgotten. What's left is to eliminate the needless dead end paths. I am asking myself if it's a good idea to use a String array to store the maze cells or if it would be much better to make a cell class that stores the String, the "visited" property and that has knowledge of its surrounding cells.

Comment: @user1812379 I would probably use a `byte[][]` for values and a `boolean[][]` for visited. Though, as long as you set visited to false at the right place, you can incorporate visited into the value array (just make it a wall or give it a separate value). I'm personally not a fan of `String[]` to represent a matrix - too immutable and unintuitive.

Comment: Thank you, but the Strings are only used to print the maze symbols. I didn't want to use numbers. For the visited flag I use a boolean array. I haven't yet understood the 2nd sentence.

Comment: @user1812379 2nd or 3rd sentence? **2nd** - Visualize - when you visit a cell, construct a wall, when you back-track, remove it. **3rd** - `String`s are immutable - you can't change them. So "set cell at row x, column y to some value" would involve getting the `String` row, changing it to a `char[]`, modifying the right value, converting it back to `String` and assigning it back into the array. For `byte[][]`, it's simply `maze[x][y] = newValue`. It's unintuitive because each row (or column) is a `String` (which is really just an array, but anyway) rather than an array, which makes more sense.

Comment: The 2nd sentence. The idea behind "eliminating unnecessary paths" is not clear.

Comment: @user1812379 Oh, *your* second sentence. Possibly look into A*. See [this](http://labs.makemachine.net/2010/03/a-star-maze-solver/) for a pretty decent version of it as a maze solver, with a nice animation.

Comment: Thanks. The shortest path is not necessary, I just want to draw the first path that has been found, but without drawing dead ends.

Comment: @user1812379 I'm not sure how you're currently display it, but either something like `setCellNotVisited()` or something like `markCellInPathArray(" ")` or both after your 4th `searchMaze` call should do it.

Answer (score 1):

You should add your flag to each recursive calls:

```
pathFound = pathFound || searchMaze(left_from_start_point, end_point, maze);
pathFound = pathFound || searchMaze(right_from_start_point, end_point, maze);
pathFound = pathFound || searchMaze(above_start_point, end_point, maze);
pathFound = pathFound || searchMaze(below_start_point, end_point, maze);
```

if pathFound is true then the calls are ignored.

Answer (score 1):

In the else block, if you set true for

```
1) cell_is_wall when wall is visited 
2) set start_point_not_within_arrary when it is not in the array
```

Then your code should work. Other recursive calls would be taken care by these conditional checks which you already have.